# 2 CA Listening on same port 7054

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have configured 2 CA for 2 Org (1 CA/1 Org). I have used Port- 7054:7054 for 1st CA and Port- 8054:8054 for 2nd CA.But when I do 'docker logs for 2nd CA container I am getting this- 2019/08/18 19:54:19 [INFO] Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7054 .Is in't it should be 8054 as I configured port 8054:8054 in docker-compose file for 2nd CA.? If yes, where I am doing wrong and where should I update?

My CA service in docker-compose file---

```
services:
  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/9a834d764f3ec2ee602e073dc27a971add2052c84024efe3e5224fa5485053e9_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/9a834d764f3ec2ee602e073dc27a971add2052c84024efe3e5224fa5485053e9_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    networks:
      - basic

  ca1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/557164d9dc484f634bc058938bac0c68fb56f60ab0359f369ececfe6c7199a53_sk
    ports:
      - "8054:8054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/557164d9dc484f634bc058938bac0c68fb56f60ab0359f369ececfe6c7199a53_sk -b admin:adminpw -d' 
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg2
    networks:
      - basic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Subhra Sankha Bose @Nipun Tharuksha

We can change default values in every open source projects

You are missing one env variable to override the default port 7054

Add this to **environment**:

```
- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=8054
```

After adding the env see below my logs

```
2019/08/19 08:34:15 [INFO] Home directory for default CA: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2019/08/19 08:34:15 [DEBUG] 1 CA instance(s) running on server
2019/08/19 08:34:15 [INFO] Operation Server Listening on 127.0.0.1:9443
2019/08/19 08:34:15 [DEBUG] TLS is enabled
2019/08/19 08:34:15 [DEBUG] TLS Certificate: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.nbd-cert.pem, TLS Key: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/8b3bb8a74b5901f03c8d0901233f5b0ea2b2800e4176dcada7ade4932df565e1_sk
2019/08/19 08:34:15 [DEBUG] Client authentication type requested: noclientcert
2019/08/19 08:34:15 [INFO] Listening on https://0.0.0.0:8054
```

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your 2nd CA with Port- 8054:7054 because internally CA is configured to listen on port 7054 only so you just have to define external port for your CA(here 8054).

Comment: Sorry, We can change the default value see below my answer

Comment: Yes, that's the way to change internal ports but there is no problem in just letting it 7054 only as the external ports are different so both the services will run independently on two different ports.

Comment: check the question, he wants to change the default port. So please strict to the question. Moreover, your statement is completely wrong. You told this >>>> `because internally CA is configured to listen on port 7054 only so` <<<< This is wrong statement

Comment: Thanks @Trinayan for your help.